# Wordpress Favicon not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress

I have uploaded my favicon to the root of my website and added this code to the header.php of my current theme.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://mywebsite.com/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"/>
<link rel="icon" href="http://mywebsite.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-ico"/>
```

After refreshing many times the Favicon doesn't show up.

The url is right as I've checked it and it works.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: I'm testing it on firefox and yes, I've tried the ctrl-F5 too.

Comment: Which browser are you trying this in? Some browsers may cache the initial icon for a whole browser session or even longer. P.S. You can also look how other sites do that, for example look how StackOverflow did: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be that your browser cached the old favicon. This cache is usually hard to clear, but try:

- Ctrl-F5 on the html page
- Open http://yourwebsite.com/favicon.ico, and Ctrl-F5

Comment: If the cache turns out to be the issue, adding junk get params to the end of the icon file should help with forcing most browsers to reload it for other users who may also it cached: e.g: ...href='http://domain.com/favicon.ico?force=1'

Comment: You probably have another browser to try it in. If it still doesn't show, you can rule out cache.

Another possibility is that your icon file is not created properly. Try uploading a currently working favicon like "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico"

Comment: Also, I don't know about wordpress, but maybe the template is cached? Have you verified the favicon url shows up in the published source code?

Comment: I've had this same issue before. If you see the Yahoo "Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site" it says (regarding favicons) that they should be cached on the server level using expires - see http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html. You might find that this is the case with your server (speculating here). So setting an expires header for your favicon might help it show up, example - http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-expires.html. It's also a good idea to understand/implement expires in general to improve page-load speeds

Answer (score -1):

Use the All in one Favicon Plugin for wordpress favicon. it's really useful and easy to use. you can even set frontend favicon and also backend favicon.

Plugin link : http://www.techotronic.de/plugins/all-in-one-favicon/

Comment: While it might be an awesome plugin it's **not relevant** to this question which proved to be local cache issue.